# how do i prevent divs from overlapping

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a layout that uses the whole screen so I have not set fixed widths on the layout. I'm using percentages.

im working on this http://www.abdhulzaman.co.uk/work/rima

as you can see at the top i have a logo and a header on the top left of the header and also a navigation thats position absolute to the right. now when i minimize the screen.. the nav and the logo header will overlap which is really annoying.

anything to do with position absolute/relative?  This may seem very simple.. would appreciate then help! thnx :)

its something similer to http://jsfiddle.net/YFCWm/

Comment: You can use float and clear CSS properties or specify a minimum width for the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the size of your navigation dynamic? If not, you could just set a `min-width` for your `header` (although it'd be better to set it in a container that wraps your entire site).

Comment: basically the header is set to 90% width

Answer (score 0):

If you're just beginning with css and layouts, it can be a good idea to use a grid based framework like twitter bootstrap or blueprint css.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

http://blueprintcss.org/

Using one of those will make your layout problem trivial.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to your problem would be to give the nav element a margin on the left side

```
margin: 0 0 0 230px;
```

That will prevent the nav from 'going' further left than 230px from the left edge of the header element.